# Calling platform.runlater multiple times javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am a bit confused about using `Platform.runLater()` in javafx, as I got `Platform.runLater()` will send the runnable paramater to thread queue, and execute it in sequential order in case it was called multiple time, as well as `Platform.runLater()` is a single javafx thread

in my javafx application I am in-need to listen to mouse and keyboard events in all **operating system not only inside javafx application**

currently I am creating two [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html)

so I am doing something like the following:

```
class FirstTimeLineWrapperClass implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
      Timeline timeline1 = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.seconds(1),
                ae -> {
                    secondPassed++;
                }));

        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }
}

class SecondTimeLineWrapperClass implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
      Timeline timeline2 = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.seconds(1),
                ae -> {
                    secondPassed++;
                }));

        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }
}
```

And then I am calling:

```
Platform.runLater(new FirstTimeLineWrapperClass());
Platform.runLater(new SecondTimeLineWrapperClass());
```

The above is kinda clutter, but just to be clear about my question,

so is it let's say ok to do so, what might go wrong in the above code?
and if `Platform.runLater()` will run in a single javafx thread, how the above code works concurrently?

As the docs mentions

> Warning : A running Timeline is being referenced from the FX runtime. Infinite Timeline might result in a memory leak if not stopped properly. All the objects with animated properties would not be garbage collected.

Comment: `Timeline`s don't run concurrently, in the sense that they don't create any new threads and the event handlers in the key frames you create are executed on the FX Application Thread. All that happens, effectively, is that the FX Application Thread is aware of them and executes any necessary code when the appropriate time arises. The comment you quoted is pretty self-explanatory: as long as the timeline is running, it can't be garbaged collected.

Comment: When I put print statement in the two `run` methods, they got printed at the same time, how this is resolved ?

Comment: What other behavior are you expecting? They are both started at (almost) the same time and both execute their handlers every second. So, each second, both key frame handlers execute.

Comment: The behavior I expected is that the first timeline will run and after a second passed the next timeline will start, as they both located inside a single javafx thread, so I am just wondering about how these handlers are working inside javafx thread, I mean how they are processed in a single thread, does javafx thread listen to events thrown by timeline handlers, and execute something upon them, if you can provide me a full explanation I would be thankful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animations don't create any additional threads, or run on any background threads.

You can think of the FX Application Thread as a loop that, in pseudocode, looks something like this (the actual details are considerably more complex):

```
while (applicationIsRunning()) {
    if (anyEventsNeedHandling()) {
        handleEvents();
    }
    processAnyRunnablesFromRunLaterQueue();
    if (timeToUpdateScene()) {
        if (animationsNeedProcessing()) {
            processAnimations();
        }
        updateScene();
    }
}
```

The way animations essentially work, is that a running animation registers itself somewhere that the main loop described above is aware of it. The animation can determine if it's time to do something - for example, in your `Timeline`s the key frame executes every second, so it's relatively easy for the `Timeline` to report if one or more key frames are due for processing, and the event handler will be invoked if necessary. The actual mechanics of this aren't specified, but that's the basic functionality.

Note that the `play()` method just starts the animation (i.e. registers it for the FX Application Thread loop to check it) and exits immediately. So in your code where you start two `Timeline`s on the FX Application thread in rapid succession, they will start immediately one after the other (effectively at almost the same time).

Consequently, you can start multiple animations, and they won't block the FX Application Thread. The usual rules apply for code being executed on the FX Application thread apply to code in any key frame handlers: it should not block and should not take a long time to run.

Also note that if you add runnables to the run-later queue faster than they can be executed, you will effectively block the FX Application Thread, giving the UI poor responsiveness (or blocking it entirely).